# Sorting array of objects in c++, repeating values

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I'm currently trying to sort an array of objects. The sort functions work fine, but if values such as `age` repeat, I would like to sort them based on, for example, `height`, and if the `height` repeats I want to sort them by `weight`. The order is based on user input.

I would like to make the program work as fast as possible, and also make it use as little memory as possible. That is why I'm posting this question, just to make sure I find the best solution.

I'm stuck. I do not know how to get repeating values in this array and sort those under different criteria at the same time, not sorting all the objects.

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
};
    
void sortByAge(int n, Person * array);
void sortByHeight(int n, Person * array);
void sortByWeight(int n, Person * array);
    
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    Person * people = new Person[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> people[i].name >> people[i].age >> people[i].weight >> people[i].height;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    int firstOrder, secondOrder, thirdOrder;
    cout << "Enter the order of sorting, choose numbers form 1 to 3, where 1 is sorting by Age, 2 is sorting by Height and 3 is sorting by weight \n";
    cin >> firstOrder >> secondOrder >> thirdOrder;

    if(firstOrder == 1) {
        sortByAge(n,people);
        if(secondOrder == 2) {
            sortByHeight(n,people);
            sortByWeight(n,people);
        } else if(secondOrder == 3) {
            sortByWeight(n,people);
            sortByHeight(n,people);
        }
    } else if(firstOrder == 2) {
        sortByHeight(n,people);
        if(secondOrder == 1) {
            sortByAge(n,people);
            sortByWeight(n,people);
        } else if(secondOrder == 3) {
            sortByWeight(n,people);
            sortByAge(n,people);
        }
    } else if(firstOrder == 3) {
        sortByWeight(n,people);
        if(secondOrder == 1) {
            sortByAge(n,people);
            sortByHeight(n,people);
        } else if (secondOrder == 2) {
            sortByHeight(n,people);
            sortByAge(n,people);
        }
    }
    delete [] people;
    return 0;
}

void sortByAge(int n, Person * array) {
    int y = 0;
    Person x;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        x = array[i];
        y = i - 1;
        while(y >= 0 && array[y].age < x.age) {
            array[y+1] = array[y];
            y--;
        }
        array[y+1] = x;
    }
}

void sortByWeight(int n, Person * array) {
    int y = 0;
    Person x;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        x = array[i];
        y = i - 1;
        while(y >= 0 && array[y].weight < x.weight) {
            array[y+1] = array[y];
            y--;
        }
        array[y+1] = x;
    }
}

void sortByHeight(int n, Person * array) {
    int y = 0;
    Person x;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        x = array[i];
        y = i - 1;
        while(y >= 0 && array[y].height < x.height) {
            array[y+1] = array[y];
            y--;
        }
        array[y+1] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to sort by multiple criteria then the code that actually does the sort needs to use those multiple criteria.

Comment: Calling one sorting function after another is not going to give you the results you want.  That will just shuffle the array around. The only result you will end up with is the output of the last function called.  You need to do all of your comparisons inside of a single function. Pass in parameters to control those comparisons.  Consider using `std::sort()` instead of writing your own sorting logic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to simplify sorting on multiple fields.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class Person{
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
};

// A comparison function taking member pointers as template parameters
// and using std::tie to compare two Persons.
template<auto... S>
bool compfunc(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs) {
    return std::tie((lhs.*S)...) < std::tie((rhs.*S)...);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Person> persons {
        {"foo", 10, 10, 10},
        {"foo", 9, 10, 10},
        {"foo", 10, 9, 10},
        {"foo", 10, 10, 9},
        {"bar", 11, 12, 13},
    };

    // Supply the sort order as template parameters where the first parameter
    // has the highest priority.
    std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end(), compfunc<&Person::name,
                                                       &Person::age,
                                                       &Person::weight,
                                                       &Person::height>);

    for(auto&[n,a,w,h] : persons) {
        std::cout << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << w << ' ' << h << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
bar 11 12 13
foo 9 10 10
foo 10 9 10
foo 10 10 9
foo 10 10 10
```

Comment: I like this pattern.  I want to

- generalize it with a variadic attribute list
- simplify it by extracting an `as_tied<S1, ...>(T&&)` helper function

Comment: @xtofl Thanks! Yes, that would be preferable in this case but I don't think that will be easy. There may be some helper functions in boost that may be able to make that possible. ... or do you mean like I just made it in the edit?

Comment: Partly, yes.  I don't know why I wrote 'attribute list' when I meant argument pack.

Comment: @xtofl Ok. I was thinking of how to make building the pack of member variable pointers flexible at runtime so that one wouldn't need to write out all possible combinations. I found that hard. I think I've seen something in boost that maybe could help with that though. [Boost PFR](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_pfr.html)